# Toggle select all rows from a button component in react-table

Tags: reactjs, react-table

Need to select all rows without using the checkbox trigger available in the table APIs. I want to get this trigger into a separate component instead of what is in the docs where one of the table column is a select all trigger.

Sandbox Playground: https://codesandbox.io/s/test-select-all-button-toggle-33c3g?file=/src/App.js

Tried to checkout options on the documentation https://react-table-omega.vercel.app/docs/api/useRowSelect#instance-properties could be a good pointer, but I haven't figured out how to get this into action.

And have it into a component as so:

```
<IconHolder
  onClick={toggleAllRows} //trigger select all rows here
>
  <Text>
    <Icon
      actionIcon
      name={true ? "ok-circled2" : "circle-thin"}
      color={globalColors.purple}
      size={20}
    />{" "}
    Select All
  </Text>
</IconHolder>
```

Comment: You should create a minimal reproducible example (preferably on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/))

Comment: @hgb123 updated with example: https://codesandbox.io/s/test-select-all-button-toggle-33c3g?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`toggleAllRowsSelected`](https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/api/useRowSelect#instance-properties) from `table` object.

> **toggleAllRowsSelected**: `Function(?set: Bool) => void` Use this function to toggle all rows as selected or not. Optionally pass `true` or `false` to set all rows to that state

```js
...

const {
  getTableProps,
  getTableBodyProps,
  headerGroups,
  rows,
  prepareRow,
  selectedFlatRows,
  state: { selectedRowPaths },
  toggleAllRowsSelected
} = table;


...
<button onClick={() => toggleAllRowsSelected()}>
  Select All Rows
</button>
```

[image: Edit test-select-all-button-toggle (forked)]

Comment: Took me ages to realise that this method is one of the properties on the `useTable` return value. I thought it would be a method on the row object similarly to `row.toggleRowSelected()` ‍♂️

Comment: How can I lift`toggleAllRowsSelected` if my button would be in a parent component?